# Helmfile + Kustomize - cannot unmarshal !!seq into state.HelmState

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kustomize, helmfile

I am trying to use the Kustomize with Helmfile by following the instructions given in [Readme](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile#helmfile--kustomize), but I am getting below error when I try to run the sync command.

```
helmfile --environment dev --file=helmfile.yaml sync
in ./helmfile.yaml: failed to read helmfile.yaml: reading document at index 1: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 4: cannot unmarshal !!seq into state.HelmState
```

helmfile.yaml

```
- name: common-virtual-services
  chart: ./common-virtual-services
  hooks:
  - events: ["prepare", "cleanup"]
    command: "./helmify"
    args: ["{{`{{if eq .Event.Name \"prepare\"}}build{{else}}clean{{end}}`}}", "{{`{{.Release.Chart}}`}}", "{{`{{.Environment.Name}}`}}"]
```

**Environment:**

helmfile version v0.119.0

kustomize - Version:3.6.1

OS - Darwin DEM-C02X5AKLJG5J 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0

Please let me know if you need more details.